# Разбиение ссылки

Tags: javascript

Я разбиваю ссылку по `/`, но мне не надо то что в скобках, как удалить `(Tested)`

```
var myString = 'https://test.com/tyu/listings/73/Desert%20Storm%20(Tested)';
var splits = myString.split('/');

console.log(splits);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var myString = 'https://test.com/tyu/listings/73/Desert%20Storm%20(Tested)';

myString = myString.replace('(Tested)',''); // уберет строку (Tested)

var splits = myString.split('/');

console.log(splits);
```

Answer (score 2):

RegExp в помощь:

```
\(.+\)
```

Демо пример для данного случая
https://regex101.com/r/zaaJmM/1

Comment: спасибо, разобрался